# English translation of */**

Tags: wildcard, nomenclature

`*/**` is read by my brain as "Give me everything in this directory and everything in it's directories, then EVERYTHING in all of their nested directories."  But by that definition, `**` should just give me the entire tree and it is two characters shorter.  Since `**` does not work this way, my definition is obviously flawed.

Is there an English translation of `*/**` that better describes what it is actually doing?

Comment: I'm wondering if this should not be called wildcard rather than regex.

Comment: Agreed. I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd translate it as "Match all contents recursively of subdirectories of the current directory". The difference from using `**` straight away is that this pattern does *not* match non-directories inside the current directory.